# Deep Profile Unity Android

Tags: android, unity3d

Профайлер в юнити имеет одну замечательную функцию - Deep Profile. За счёт более высоких затрат ресурсов она позволяет отследить нагрузку вплоть до функции в скрипте. К сожалению, когда я запускаю проект на Android устройстве, даже с нажатой кнопкой Deep Profile профайлер выдает результаты обычного профайла, не дип, без указания точного скрипта или тем более функции. Я понимаю, что это большая нагрузка для смартфона, но, быть может, как то можно включить Deep профайл не только в редакторе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[В инструкции Профайлеру](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/ProfilerWindow.html), написано, что нужно просто подключить профайлер, а затем перевести его в режим "глубокого профилирования". В той же инструкции написано, что в некоторых случаях эта функция может быть недоступная вовсе из-за сложности кода.

Так же советуют заниматься ручным рефакторингом, в котором вам помогут методы  [Profiler.BeginSample](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Profiler.BeginSample.html) и [Profiler.EndSample](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/Profiler.EndSample.html). С их помощью вы можете узнать сколько времени тратится на конкретные операции и задать им имена, под которыми они станут отображаться в профайлере.

Comment: ссылки на методы устарели. сейчас https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Profiling.Profiler.BeginSample.html